# Running progress bar while another task is being run android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have an activity class where when a button is clicked i calls a function which updates some data. Below is the function
"startDIImport"

This function internally uses Thread.sleep(10000) to wait for another task to be completed.

Hence while this function is in progress i am planning to show a progress bar.
"showProgress" is the function which shows the progress bar.

I have written below code to show progress bar while my task runs in oncreate function

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showProgress();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startDIImport();
        }
    }).start();
```

But my progressbar hangs when i click the button. Can you please help in resolving this issue.

I have checked AsyncTask but came to know that this has to be used only if the background task runs for few seconds. My background task may run to few hours.
Can you please let me know the best solution to handle this.

Comment: Can you show your `onClick` method ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Hi, Thanks for the reply. On clicking the button i am calling another activity. I am creating above threads in the onCreate function of the new activity.

Comment: So you have 2 activity for that ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Yes.I have two activities. When a button is clicked on first activity, i am creating new activity and creating the above two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to run code on the ui thread. Also, you should never Thread.sleep(), use a proper callback mechanism instead. Show more code, it's hard to see what you're trying to do.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showProgress();
            }
        });
```